# How to simulate bouncing ball? odeint not applicable?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

Here is a code simulating the simplest falling ball:

```
%pylab
from scipy.integrate import odeint
ts = linspace(0, 1)
def f(X, t):
    dx0 = X[1]
    dx1 = -9.8
    return [dx0, dx1]
X = odeint(f, [2, 0], ts)
plot(ts, X[:, 0])
```

But how about a ball bouncing at y=0?

I know that, in general, collision is a difficult part of physics simulations. However, I wonder if it's really not possible to simulate this simple system, hopefully with odeint.

Comment: Your ``f(X,t)`` is independent of ``t``, which does make sense. Check http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#ordinary-differential-equations-odeint for a similar example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is just to add a big force that kicks the particle out from the forbidden region. This requires an ODE solver that is able to handle "stiff" problems, but luckily `odeint` uses `lsoda` which automatically switches to a mode suitable for such problems.

For example,

```
F(x) = { 0              if x > 0
       { big_number     if x < 0
```

The numerical solver will have slightly easier time if the step function is rounded a bit, for example, `F(x) = big_number / (1 + exp(x/width))`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

big_number = 10000.0
width = 0.0001

ts = np.linspace(0, 10, 2000)
def f(X, t):
    dx0 = X[1]
    dx1 = -9.8
    dx1 += big_number / (1 + np.exp(X[0]/width))
    return [dx0, dx1]

with np.errstate(over='ignore'):
    # don't print overflow warning messages from exp(),
    # and limit the step size so that the solver doesn't step too deep
    # into the forbidden region
    X = odeint(f, [2, 0], ts, hmax=0.01)
plt.plot(ts, X[:, 0])
plt.show()
```