# Can I limit scipy.integrate.odeint to a boundary condition?

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I would like a free falling object to "bounce". In a simplistic example, an object drops in free fall from an initial height. I would like it to "bounce", when it hits "the ground".

In the example, an object drops with an initial velocity of zero and accelerates at one g. Is there a way to force odeint to terminate its "integration", from its 'x' position rather than after an elapsed time?

Or does scipy offer a better approach to the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def gravity (x, t, params):
    # x = (x, x')
    # Ordinary differential equations for displacement and velocity
    # of object in frictionless free-fall.
    g = params
    return [g*t, g]

# First 2 seconds of motion
t = np.arange (0, 2.1, 0.1)
g = -9.8  # m/s^2
bc = np.array ([9.8, 0])
soln = odeint (gravity, bc, t, args = (g,))

# How do we limit odeint to free fall until contact with the ground at x = 0?

fig = plt.figure (1, figsize = (8,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(t, soln [:,0])
ax1.set_xlabel ('time')
ax1.set_ylabel ('x')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1.plot(t, soln [:,1])
ax1.set_xlabel ('time')
ax1.set_ylabel ('Vx')

plt.show ()
```

Comment: You may find [this answer helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28649124/190597).

Comment: Thanks. In a pinch, I could try something like that. In my full problem, I anticipate a very short manipulation of the positional and velocity parameters - for a real bounce including the spin of the object. At which point the initial functions will then be used, but with a new "free falling" component of the trajectory.